# Two different login pages according to ID using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $query = "SELECT *
              FROM users
              WHERE username = '".mysql_escape_string($username)."'
              AND password = '".mysql_escape_string($password)."'";
        $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
```

Now this is my query for general visitors, now if i need a admin and moderator how can i process from the same users with a specific ID alone.

My SQL Query.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `yourID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(26) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(26) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`yourID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=87992 ;
```

The login page will be the same for admin and moderator.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but normally a login system shouldn't make any difference between user roles. After logging in, you can check the logged in user's rights and and give him access to restricted areas of your application.

Comment: This is definitely the way to approach user authentication. Anything more complicates the process unnecessarily. +1

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding what you want, but you could add another column to your users table to distinguish between the different types of user. You could add an integer column for this:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD userlevel tinyint NOT NULL default 0;
```

Then you could set this according to what you want to let the user do, e.g.

```
0 = normal user 
1 = moderator 
2 = admin
etc.
```

When the user logs in you can then retrieve this value in the query and use it/store it in the session etc. in order to grant access to restricted actions.

You could also look at using the MySQL enum type for this as an alternative to the integer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand this question. But I recently implemented a login system where I needed a user account and a admin account. I added a column to my users table that was "privilege" which I then stored a numeric number that related to that user's privilege level. Then on restricted pages I just checked to see if the user had the required level of access to view the page.

- Add privilege (tinyInt) attribute user table.
- Add active (Boolean) attribute to
  user table.
- Add cookie (varchar) attribute to
  user table.

//Ran when page is accessed

checkLogin($privilege){

```
//Use Cookie to determine which user is accessing page
//Determine if user is active (toggled when logged in)
//retrieve users privilege level
//check against passed in value 
//return true or false
```

}

//Php for website.

if(checkLogin(0)){

```
//0 – guest
//1 – user
//3 – admin
```

}

Comment: Yes this is my exact requirement, can you give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to differentiate between 'normal users' and 'admins'. Why not just add another column to your users table, e.g. AdminStatus and make it an int, zero for no, one for yes. Then in your login query just check the AdminStatus.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a field of user type to the table,
and you know what is the group user